# How to display CellObjects as Cells in PopupWindow

Tags: cells

I am attempting to use a celltag ("temp") to display an entire cell in a PopupWindow.  To see what I am attempting to do,  open a new notebook and evaluate the following:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationCell[],CellTags->"temp"]
```

Now, in a new cell, evaluate the following:

```
PopupWindow["Click Me", RawBoxes[NotebookRead[Cells[CellTags -> {"temp"}]]],ShowCellBracket -> True]
```

The resulting output is a button labeled "Click Me".  When you click this button a PopupWindow appears containing the contents of the cell with celltag "temp".  My problem is that I am only grabbing the contents of the cell in the PopupWindow and not the entire cell.

I would like the entire cell including the grayed out section to to the right.  I turned on the cellbrackets for clarity.  It appears I am only grabbing the text.  I can't figure out how to grab the entire cell and display it in the PopupWindow.  Any ideas?

BTW... my goal is to create buttons that appear as words in a text cell that when clicked will display a popup containing definitions grabbed from other cells in the notebook.

[image]

Comment: It seems like it would be better to copy and paste the cellobject but I’m not sure how to do that and make it display as a cell as opposed to a cellobject.

Comment: Like this: `EventHandler["Click Me", 
 "MouseClicked" :> 
  NotebookPut@
   Notebook[NotebookRead[Cells[CellTags -> {"temp"}]], 
    WindowSize -> Small]
 ]`?

Comment: Thanks Kuba! This works!  If you add it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: also `Button["Click Me",  CreateDocument[NotebookRead[Cells[CellTags -> {"temp"}]]], 
 Appearance -> "Frameless"]`?